# PHP Read files inside of the server root

Tags: php, server, root, fopen, fread

In my current PHP script I am attempting to read files which are not inside of `/var/www/html` (which the script seems to be limited too) but files inside of `/root/` or anywhere behind `/var/www/html`.

Just to explain why, I need to read critical data from files which I do not want downloadable or accessible under any circumstances (no matter how much verification).

I have messed around with `getcwd()` and `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` but with no success.

My question: Is this even possible, and if so, how can I do this?

P.S. My method of reading is just standard `fopen($filename, "rb")` and `fread`;

Comment: maybe `file_get_contents()` could work?

Comment: What is your `open_basedir` set to?

Comment: file_get_contents() takes the parameter of $filename, therefore my system would not be affected. I need to be able to read from a file inside root directory, file_get_contents() will assume just take the same as fread

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` and look at your `open_basedir` value is. That value "Limit[s] the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree".

Answer (score 0):

It depends if php has the permissions to access the required files. You'll need to allow permissions for the user "www-data" (if you're using apache on linux) to be able to read the files.

Comment: Would you be able to be more specific on how to allow php permissions for this?
I have added the root user to the www-data group and also allowed them permissions to /root/ and /var/www/html/. 

From there, how would i go to reading from root as the PHP script defaults to its running directory.

Comment: There should be no need to add the root user to the www-data group. It is root! You should store these files in a directory outside your web root, but that the Apache server user (www-data we assume) can access. I would not use `/root/` directory in this at all.

Comment: I have manged to fix it by allowing www-data to access /, therefore allowing me to backout of the PHP directory with just a simple "../../../../root/".
Thank you for your help as it really did help